# How to properly place hyphens in a suspended compound that includes a parenthesis?

Tags: parentheses, suspended-hyphen

What is the correct way to format the bolded portion of this sentence with respect to hyphens and associated spaces?

> A set of approaches that mitigates these issues, by learning the optimal control with respect to the **full- (or infinite-) time horizon**, stems from reinforcement learning.

Normally, I would say "the full-time horizon" or "the infinite-time horizon".

Comment: 1. What is it trying to say? 2. When you say *format*, are you asking about *phrasing* or *markup*?

Comment: I want it to say that all of the approaches in the set of approaches learn the optimal control, while considering either the full-time horizon or infinite-time horizon. By format, I'm referring to the placement of the hyphens and pertaining spaces.

Comment: I would omit the brackets: **full- or infinite-time horizon**  The effect of putting something in brackets is to reduce the emphasis or add it as an afterthought or an aside.

Comment: ... with respect to the full-time or infinite-time horizon.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Stack Exchange comments are considered ephemeral; I've edited the question to reflect the new information.

Comment: Whilst **full- or infinite-time horizon** would work, I want to convey that the **infinite-time** case is much less common, hence my use of parenthesis.